# Таблица умножения, как нарисовать линии

Tags: c#

Есть такой код

```
for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
            {
                for (int n = 1; n < 11; n++)
                {
                    Console.Write("{0} ", i * n);
                    if (n == 10)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine();
                    }
                }

            }
```

выдаёт результат

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20
3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30
4 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40
5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50
6 12 18 24 30 36 42 48 54 60
7 14 21 28 35 42 49 56 63 70
8 16 24 32 40 48 56 64 72 80
9 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81 90
10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100
```

нужно нарисовать линии

```
1 | 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
- | ------------------------
2 | 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20
3 | 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30
4 | 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40
5 | 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50
6 | 12 18 24 30 36 42 48 54 60
7 | 14 21 28 35 42 49 56 63 70
8 | 16 24 32 40 48 56 64 72 80
9 | 18 27 36 45 54 63 72 81 90
10 |  20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90 100
```

как можно вывести линии?
Пробовал разные условия но результат не тот.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for (int i = 1; i < 11; i++)
{
  Console.Write("{0} | ", i);
  for (int n = 2; n < 11; n++)
  {
    Console.Write("{0} ", i * n);
  }
  Console.WriteLine();
  if (i == 1) {
    Console.WriteLine("- | --------------------------");
  }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо рабоатет!

Comment: @EugeneTM Отлично! Пожалуйста.